# What is a "Reporting Task for Subplan" task in SSIS, and how can I create one?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to script a daily full backup to a job using an SSIS package. I've inherited several databases from a previous DBA, and I'm trying to emulate the ones he made in order to be consistent. Most of it is pretty straightforward, but there is one task called "Reporting Task for subplan {*GUID*}" which I am not sure how to create or use:

[image: What is Reporting Task for Subplan]

No task by that name appears to be in the Toolbox pane in BIDS, nor does any task appear to exist which has that icon. Neither Books Online nor Google searches are returning any real documentation or discussion about it. Presumably it's used for logging, since a logfile is specified in its properties.

What is this task and how can I create one, so that I can build packages similar to what my predecessor was building?

Comment: That sounds like your are looking @ a maintenance plan in BIDS. I'd suggest opening the plan directly, and not trying to edit it in BIDS.

Comment: @EricHiggins That is correct; I didn't think there was a difference. I exported it from the server and opened it on my workstation. What was the clue?

Comment: subplan is maint plan lingo :) Try making your mods in the maint plan directly and stuff like GUIDs are obscured, don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @EricHiggins Sure enough, if I create these same tasks as a Maintenance Plan, export to my desktop, and open in BIDS, I see the Reporting Task. I'd write this up as an answer myself, but I'd rather let you have the rep if you'd like to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please open them in SSMS Maintenance Plans instead of using BIDS to open them & you won't have to worry about the GUIDs. The task you're asking about is created automatically when you make a maintenance plan in SSIS.